# trying to set the data value of submit button

Tags: jquery

I've been having problems trying to set the data value of an elment. I have the following:

```
<textarea class='pairing-comment' ></textarea>
<input data-comment="" data-global-id="187"
       type="submit" id="pairing-comment-submit">
```

I'd like to update the the data-comment value when the user changes the textarea (testing has shown this to be the only reliable way to get this done):

```
$('textarea.pairing-comment').on('keyup',function() {
    var com = $(this).val();
    console.log("here i am in pairing-comment " + com);  // works fine
    $('#pairing-comment-submit').
         data('comment', com);  // not writing to the data-comment elment
});
```

What would be the jquery syntax to write what I want to the data-comment value?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the attribute `data-comment` to be updated, then you have to use

```
$('#pairing-comment-submit').attr('data-comment', com);
```

when you use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), it updates the value to a internal data structure maintained by jQuery instead of changing the attribute value

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DEvZ6/)

Comment: yeah, I know you're right but it's not working for me as is.